# What is the name of the OpenSSL date format?

Tags: openssl, expiration-date

The OpenSSL date format has the month first and the year after the time.

Example: Mar 18 10:55:00 2017 GMT

See also here: https://www.shellhacks.com/openssl-check-ssl-certificate-expiration-date/

Does anyone know the name of the standard behind this format if there is one ?

Comment: I don't think that this is a security question. But this is just the format returned by [asctime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/asctime.html) which is part of the ISO C standard.

Comment: But the day from asctime is missing in this format.

Comment: You are right. According to the code [ASN1_TIME_print](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/ASN1_TIME_print.html) is used which according to the documentation prints a *"human readable format"*. I doubt that there are any date formatting standards are involved here. Anyway, still off-topic.